# Conditionally resuming a list

Tags: lists, enumerate, conditionals, examples

I have defined an environment viz. `Examples` in the following way:

```
\newtheoremstyle{myexcstyle}{3ex}{3ex}{}{}{\scshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexcstyle}
\newtheorem*{exmps}{Examples}
\newenvironment{Exmps}[1][]
{%
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {\begin{exmps}}{\begin{exmps}[#1]}
        \leavevmode\vspace{-1ex}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., font=\bfseries, itemsep=1.5ex]
        }
        {
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{exmps}
}
```

What I neeed is when the note/comment `[continued]` is passed through the environment, it should resume the `enumerate` numbering. This should happen only when the comment is present. Otherwise it should always start a new list. Ideally, the following MWE

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newtheoremstyle{myexcstyle}{3ex}{3ex}{}{}{\scshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexcstyle}
\newtheorem*{exmps}{Examples}
\newenvironment{Exmps}[1][]
{%
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
        {\begin{exmps}}{\begin{exmps}[#1]}
        \leavevmode\vspace{-1ex}
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., font=\bfseries, itemsep=1.5ex]
            }
            {
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{exmps}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{Exmps}
        \item   Example 1
    \end{Exmps}

    \begin{Exmps}
        \item   Example 1
    \end{Exmps}

%   After some theorems and results on the same topic

    \begin{Exmps}[continued]
        \item   Example 2
    \end{Exmps}

\end{document}
```

should generate the following output. How do I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose to use `etoolbox`'s `\ifstrequal` macro. In order to be able to (non-locally) interleave non-resumable and resumable examples, I believe you need a dedicated `enumerate` *series* in `enumitem`-speak, which I called `resumable-series` here. Of course, the series name could come from an argument of your `Exmps` environment in case you would need to have several independent resumable series.

When starting the `resumable` series, use `start` in the optional argument of the `Exmps` environment. When resuming it, use `continued` (I think `resume` would be a better keyword to go with `start`, but I'm following the naming scheme from your question as much as possible). When you pass no such argument to the `Exmps` environment, you get an example from the non-resumable series.

Note that I replaced your `\leavevmode\vspace{-1ex}` with `\mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip -0.5ex\@nobreaktrue` to make sure there is no page break after example headings.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% \usepackage{thmtools} % not needed here
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtheoremstyle{myexcstyle}{3ex}{3ex}{}{}{\scshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexcstyle}

\newtheorem*{exmps}{Examples}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\my@start@example}[2]{%
  \begin{exmps}#1%
  % \@nobreaktrue prevents the list environment used by enumerate from
  % inserting \@beginparpenalty, which would allow a page break.
  \mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip -0.5ex\@nobreaktrue
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., font=\bfseries, itemsep=1.5ex, #2]%
}

\newenvironment{Exmps}[1][]
  {%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{start}
      {\my@start@example{}{series=resumable-series}}%
      {%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{continued}
          {\my@start@example{[continued]}{resume=resumable-series}}
          {\my@start@example{}{}}%
      }%
  }
  {\end{enumerate}%
   \end{exmps}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{Exmps}
      \item   Example 1
  \end{Exmps}

  \begin{Exmps}[start]       % start the 'resumable-series' series
      \item   Example 1
  \end{Exmps}

  \begin{Exmps}[continued]   % resume the 'resumable-series' series
      \item   Example 2
  \end{Exmps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the following input:

```latex
\begin{Exmps}
    \item   Non-resumable
    \item   other item
\end{Exmps}

\begin{Exmps}[start]       % start the 'resumable-series' series
    \item   Resumable, first
    \item   other item
    \item   other item
\end{Exmps}

\begin{Exmps}
    \item   Non-resumable
    \item   other item
\end{Exmps}

\begin{Exmps}[continued]
    \item   Resumable, an item
    \item   other item
\end{Exmps}

\begin{Exmps}[continued]
    \item   Resumable, an item
    \item   Last item.
\end{Exmps}
```

you would get:

[image]

Comment: That's dope! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I made a small change to *actually* prevent page breaks after example headings. You can verify that it works using `\usepackage[paperheight=3.04cm]{geometry}` or `\usepackage[paperheight=3.05cm]{geometry}` in the full example.