# How to produce the list environment header by cross-referencing an item by `\cref'

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumitem, cleveref, varioref

As suggested by the accepted answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530964/conditionally-resuming-a-list) asked by me, I am using the same code snippet for my `Examples` environment.

Now recently I learnt about the `varioref` and `cleveref` packages and started using them. In this regard, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheoremstyle{myexcstyle}{3ex}{3ex}{}{}{\scshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexcstyle}
\newtheorem*{exmps}{Examples}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\my@start@example}[2]{%
    \begin{exmps}#1
        \mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip -0.5ex\@nobreaktrue
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., font=\bfseries, ref=\arabic*, itemsep=1.5ex, #2]%
        }
        
        \newenvironment{Exmps}[1][]
        {%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{start}
            {\my@start@example{}{series=resumable-series}}%
            {%
                \ifstrequal{#1}{continued}
                {\my@start@example{[continued]}{resume=resumable-series}}
                {\my@start@example{}{}}%
            }%
        }
        {\end{enumerate}%
    \end{exmps}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{Exmps}{Example}{Examples}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Exmps}
        \item \label{1}
                First example
        \item \label{2}
                Second example
    \end{Exmps}
    \vref{1}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

How can I change the prefix string 'item', which is produced by `\vref`, to 'example'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Exmps` environment in your code invokes a level-1 `enumerate` environment. The counter associated with this environment is called `enumi`. The instruction

```
\crefname{Exmps}{Example}{Examples}
```

does not have the effect you desire because the relevant counter variable that needs to be in the first argument of `\crefname` is not `Exmps` but `enumi`. The `cleveref` package contains code that associates the counter `enumi` (as well as it siblings `enumii`, `enumiii`, etc) with the label string 'item'. This is why `\vref` produces 'item' as the prefix string in your example.

Now, I believe it would be a very bad idea to run `\crefname{enumi}{Example}{Examples}`, since level-1 enumerated environments may occur elsewhere in your document as well, right?

The solution is to use the machinery of the `enumitem` package -- specifically, the package's `\newlist` and `\setlist` commands -- to create a bespoke enumerate-like environment that gets all the formatting features you wish. In the solution below, this bespoke environment is called `examplenum`, and the associated counter is called `examplenumi`. Now, `\crefname{examplenumi}{Example}{Examples}` does have the desired effect on the output of `\vref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newlist{examplenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examplenum]{label=\arabic*., font=\bfseries, 
                    ref=\arabic*, itemsep=1.5ex, left=0pt}
\crefname{examplenumi}{Example}{Examples}

\newtheoremstyle{myexcstyle}{3ex}{3ex}{}{}{\scshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexcstyle}
\newtheorem*{exmps}{Examples}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\my@start@example}[2]{%
   \begin{exmps}#1
   \mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip -0.5ex\@nobreaktrue
   \begin{examplenum}[#2]}
\newenvironment{Exmps}[1][]{%
   \ifstrequal{#1}{start}
   {\my@start@example{}{series=resumable-series}}%
   {\ifstrequal{#1}{continued}
     {\my@start@example{[continued]}{resume=resumable-series}}
     {\my@start@example{}{}}}}
   {\end{examplenum}%
    \end{exmps}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Exmps}
   \item \label{ex:1} First example
   \item \label{ex:2} Second example
\end{Exmps}
\clearpage % force a page break
\vref{ex:1} \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please comment on my follow-up question?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul - Your follow-up question is mostly an entirely new question. Please consider posting a new query (and deleting the addendum from the present query).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541704/how-to-produce-the-section-header-by-cross-referencing-a-subsubitem-in-the-enu