# How to show the chapter number when cross-referencing enumerated items via `\cref'

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

In my book, the `exercise` section is defined as follows:

```
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[exercise]{
    label*=\thechapter.\arabic*.,
    ref=\thechapter.\arabic*, 
    before={%
        \section*{\hfil{Exercises -- \thechapter}}%
        \markright{\S Exercises -- \thechapter}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises -- \thechapter}%
        \setlist*[enumerate,1]{ref=\theexercisei.~\arabic*}%
        \setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\alph*)}%
    },
}
\setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\alph*)}
```

When cross-referencing an item from the Exercise using `\cref`, taking a cue from the answer in [this earlier question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541444/how-to-produce-the-list-environment-header-by-cross-referencing-an-item-by-cre), I added the following snippet to my code:

```
\crefname{exercisei}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{exerciseii}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{exerciseiii}{exercise}{exercises}
```

The output is half-baked. It produces "exercise 1.1 in page #" properly but it fails for lower-level items. There it shows the prefix string "item" for the subitem and subsubitem. How to fix the later parts? Please help.

Below is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[exercise]{
    label*=\thechapter.\arabic*.,
    ref=\thechapter.\arabic*, 
    before={%
        \section*{\hfil{Exercises -- \thechapter}}%
        \markright{\S Exercises -- \thechapter}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises -- \thechapter}%
        \setlist*[enumerate,1]{ref=\theexercisei.~\arabic*}%
        \setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\alph*)}%
    },
}
\setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\alph*)}

\crefname{exercisei}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{exerciseii}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{exerciseiii}{exercise}{exercises}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{One}
    \begin{exercise}
        \item \label{1}
                First exercise.
        \item 
                \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
                    \item \label{1a}
                            Question
                            \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), font=\itshape, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
                                \item \label{1ai}
                                        Qn
                            \end{enumerate}
                \end{enumerate}
    \end{exercise}
    \newpage
    \vref{1}, \vref{1a}, \vref{1ai}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Overall, I can't say I understand what you are trying to achieve. If you employ`enumerate` (rather than `exercise`) environments to create the lists, don't be surprised if `\cref` and `\vref` use the label "item" in their cross-referencing call-outs. It might be a good idea if you explained in words what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: To answer your first query, I tried that option without the desired result. What I want to achieve is the code `\vref{1a}` should produce **exercise 1.(a) in page #** and `\vref{1ai}` should produce **exercise 1.(a)(i) in page#**.

Comment: A little typo in the last comment: `\vref{1a}` should produce **exercise 1.2.(a) in page #** and `\vref{1ai}` should produce **exercise 1.2.(a)(i) in page #** according to the MWE.

Comment: In my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541448/5001) to an earlier question of yours, I wrote that it was a good idea to (a) *not* modify the default properties of LaTeX's basic `enumerate` list environments and (b) create separate, bespoke enumerate-like list environments. Your present code satisfies criterion (b) but violates criterion (a) massively. Is this deliberate?

Comment: Honestly speaking, I do not have much idea about that. I researched in this site (mostly) to get my desired output and came up with the above-mentioned code. I was _ok-ishly_ happy with it and with `\ref`. After you introduced me with the option of `\vref` I am trying to switch to the automated cross-reference mode. So it would be perfectly alright for me to accept any alteration in the code you want to make as long as the `exercise` produces the current output and `\cref` produces my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in an earlier comment, I think it's a poor idea to overwrite the default properties of the basic `enumerate` list environment -- unless you're absolutely sure that you will never, ever use `enumerate` environments elsewhere in your document.

I strongly recommend that you use the machinery of the `enumitem` package -- specifically, its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros -- to define 3 levels (or more, if you wish) of a custom enumerate-like list environment. In the code below, I've chosen the name `exlist` for this new list environment; naturally, you're free to come up with a different name -- as long as it's not `enumerate`... The counters associated with level-1, level-2, and level-3 `exlist` lists are called `exlisti`, `exlistii`, and `exlistiii`. To inform `cleveref` (and, indirectly, `varioref`) how such objects should be cross-referenced, issue suitable `\crefname` directives as well; see below.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{exlist}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[exlist,1]{left=0pt,
         label=\thechapter.\arabic*.,
         ref=  \thechapter.\arabic*, 
         before={%
             \section*{\centering Exercises -- \chaptername\ \thechapter}
             \markright{\S\  Exercises -- \chaptername\ \thechapter}
             \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises -- \thechapter}}
        }
\setlist[exlist,2]{left=0pt,
         label=(\alph*),
         ref=  \theexlisti.(\alph*)
        }
\setlist[exlist,3]{left=0pt,nosep,
         label=(\textit{\roman*}),
         ref=  \theexlistii(\textit{\roman*})
        }

% Load 'varioref' first, 'hyperref' second, 'cleveref' third:
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{exlisti}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{exlistii}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{exlistiii}{exercise}{exercises}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\begin{exlist} % start a level-1 list
\item \label{1} First exercise.
\item \begin{exlist} % start a level-2 list
      \item \label{12a} First part of the second exercise.
            \begin{exlist} % start a level-3 list
            \item \label{12ai}  Qn 1
            \item \label{12aii} Qn 2
            \end{exlist}
      \item \label{12b} Second part of the second exercise.
      \end{exlist}
\end{exlist}


\newpage
\vref{1}

\Vref{12a,12b}

\vref{12ai,12aii}
\end{document}
```